# Adding static header name while making dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am making a table which row & column depend on JSON

JSON:

```
     $scope.dataToShow=[

            tableHeder=["First Name","Age"],

            {
                name:"rahim",
                age:23
            },
            {
                name:"karim",
                age:24
            }
        ];
```

My code:

```
<table>
      <tr>
         <th>Select</th>
         <th ng-repeat="header in dataToShow.tableHeader"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in dataToShow">
           <td>
               <input type="checkbox">
           </td>
            <td ng-repeat="item in row">{{item}}</td>
        </tr>
 </table>
```

I want my view like:

Select   Name  age

---

checkbox rahim 23

---

checkbox karim 24

---

But my I am getting:

Select

---

Checkbox Name age

---

Checkbox rahim 23

---

Checkbox karim 24

How can I solve it???

Comment: Where is the JSON ?Show us

Comment: This is not at all a valid JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the JSON response is not from backend, do some modifications

**JSON**:

```
$scope.dataToShow={

        tableHeder:["First Name","Age"],

        tableData: [{
            name:"rahim",
            age:23
        },
        {
            name:"karim",
            age:24
        }]
    };
```

**HTML**:

```
<table>
      <tr>
         <th>Select</th>
         <th ng-repeat="header in dataToShow.tableHeader">{{header}}</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in dataToShow.tableData">
           <td>
               <input type="checkbox">
           </td>
            <td >{{row.name}}</td>
            <td >{{row.age}}</td>
        </tr>
 </table>
```

This will definitely work

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
 <table>
          <tr>
             <th>Select</th>
             <th>{{dataToShow.tableHeder[0]}}</th>
             <th>{{dataToShow.tableHeder[1]}}</th>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="row in dataToShow">
               <td>
                   <input type="checkbox">
               </td>
                <td >{{row.name}}</td>
                <td >{{row.age}}</td>
            </tr>
     </table>
```

Using `$index` you can get the index number of the loop.

Comment: `dataToShow` is an array. So do you think  `dataToShow.tableHeader` will work?

Comment: After small modification in that array , this code will work .